# Kernel of a homomorphism: $f(a)=f(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose $A$ and $K$ are rings with $f: A \to  K$ a homomorphism.

Prove that for any $x \in a + \ker(f)$ we have $f(x)=f(a)$.

Im not sure how to start this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $x = a + b$ for $b \in \text{Ker}(f)$. Then $f(x) = f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b) = f(a) + 0 = f(a)$.